# conflicting declaration of static QMap

Tags: c++, qt, static, qmap

I have a simple Customer class with 3 static QMap

```
//customer.h

class Customer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    static QMap<Customer::Type, QString> const names;
    static QMap<QString, Customer::Type> const keywords;
    static QMap<Customer::Type, QString> const debugStrings;
};
```

Customer::Type is a Enum, but this is not relevant to the problem

```
//customer.cpp

//QMap<QString, Customer::Type> const Customer::names = Customer::initNames();
QMap<QString, Customer::Type> const Customer::keywords = Customer::initKeywords();
QMap<Customer::Type, QString> const Customer::debugStrings = Customer::initDebugStrings();
```

all three init function have been tested and work perfectly fine, they are defined exactly the same way and are all static

For some reason, I cannot uncomment the names in .cpp. If I do, I get the following error :

```
error: conflicting declaration 'const QMap<QString, Customer::Type> Customer::names'
```

I tried renaming, moving it somewhere else, it always is this one that doesn't work, and I don't know why ?

But the other ones worked with no issue..

Comment: Do you have a class method with the same name? Anyway, you should provide full class declaration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your cpp file you have the template parameters in the wrong order:

```
QMap<QString, Customer::Type> const Customer::names = Customer::initNames();
```

should be:

```
QMap<Customer::Type, QString> const Customer::names = Customer::initNames();
```

Or the variable declaration in your header file should be changed depending on the return type of `Customer::initNames()`

Comment: I feel really dumb now :-) thank you so much, I've been loosing my head around this for almost an hour

Comment: This kind of mistake is easy to miss :)

Comment: classic copy paste mistake :)